# Please set the GIT_USER environment variable or explicitly specify USE_SSH

Tags: npm, deployment, environment-variables, github-pages, docusaurus

I'm encountering an issue while trying to deploy my Docusaurus site using the `npm run deploy` command. Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image: Please set the GIT_USER environment variable or explicitly specify USE_SSH]

**OR**

```
Error: Please set the GIT_USER environment variable, or explicitly specify USE_SSH instead!
```

I'm using Docusaurus version 3.1.1 and Node version v20.10.0. Below is the full error log:

```less
[WARNING] When deploying to GitHub Pages, it is better to use an explicit "trailingSlash" site config.
Otherwise, GitHub Pages will add an extra trailing slash to your site urls only on direct-access (not when navigation) with a server redirect.
This behavior can have SEO impacts and create relative link issues.

[INFO] Deploy command invoked...

Error: Please set the GIT_USER environment variable, or explicitly specify USE_SSH instead!
    at Command.deploy (F:\personal-sites\code-harbor-hub\node_modules\@docusaurus\core\lib\commands\deploy.js:70:19)

[INFO] Docusaurus version: 3.1.1
Node version: v20.10.0
```

I've tried troubleshooting by checking my environment variables, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Can someone please guide me on how to fix this error and successfully deploy my Docusaurus site?